# How to fix IntelliJ IDEA 2016 TypeScript Error, "Cannot start compiler process"

Tags: intellij-idea, typescript

After setting up IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2.x with a TypeScript compiler, in my case Node v6.2.1, I get a TypeScript Project Error as follows:

"Error: Cannot start compiler process"

This started happening after IntelliJ was upgraded to 2016.2.x. Previous versions worked fine.

Here's how I setup the TypeScript compiler:
[image]

Here's the error message:
[image]

Comment: I reported this issue here, please vote: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-23344

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To fix this problem, directly edit the TypeScript configuration within the project's .idea directory. Within the project structure, navigate to your .idea directory then locate and open file typescript-compiler.xml like below.
[image: Direct Edit]

Now add the following xml option element after the "useConfig" option element (make sure to use the path appropriate your node installation):

```
<option name="nodeInterpreterTextField" value="$PROJECT_DIR$/../../node/bin/node" />
```

Be sure to change the directory path to your instance of node.
[image: Fixed]

Sadly, this solution we be overridden every time you edit and save your settings. Hopefully, IDEA will have a fix for this soon.

Comment: Had the same problem and this fixed it for me on 2016.2.2   - Thanks!

Comment: this does not help on WebStorm 2016.3.1 and TypeScript 2.1.X

Answer (score 0):

First, I ran:
npm install gulp-typescript typescript --save-dev

Then, I downloaded 2017.1.4 version of WebStorm and reinstalled WebStorm.

Everything works fine after that.